# How to move an active window on a second screen?

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors

I have Windows 7 with dual monitor, I need to move on a second screen and active window using a Windows shortcut.

Could you tell me if it is possible using only Win 7? Alternatively could you suggest me an alternative?

Comment: Press "Win + Left/Right" key twice

Comment: @nixda, you've had a reply. GibboK please use the `@` to alert the person you're talking to them (as I have done to nixda)

Comment: Dexpot is the answer, search for it on Google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nixda has already provided one option in the comments of the OP

You can also press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>← (Left cursor)</kbd> or <kbd>→ (Right cursor)</kbd>

The advantage of this is it moves the entire screen across and maintains it's relative position and size.

Comment: +1; That is so handy. I love Windows Key+Arrow Key but it's annoying that you have to press it multiple times and loose your sizing. More fool me for assuming there couldn't be a better option.